# Continue list on a new line when a box's height is restricted

Tags: css, list, menu

I'm currently working on a menu design and i've been fiddling round with a few different layouts and techniques. Currently i'm looking at a hover menu design with expanding boxes containing links. Only issue is because i've set the box to have `max-height: 400px;` it means currently any list i create eg. `<li>1</li><li>2</li>` etc. just continues down the box and outside it rather than onto the next line. Anybody know how to force it to move to the right and act as if it was starting a new list?

Comment: Is your desired situation that you want multiple columns when there are more items than fit in the box vertically?

Comment: Yes those are the words i was looking for. Knew what i wanted to put but couldn't think of the right context. How would i go about this?

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS3 [`column-count`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/) property, this will split the content into 3 parts, the support is yet lil dicey but this will be the perfect approach for what you are looking for

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ajAzC/)

```
div {
    background: #eee;
    height: 120px;
    column-count:3;
    -moz-column-count:3; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-column-count:3; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Comment: I like the idea and it will come in handy in future. However is there no way of writing the CSS so that in the circumstance it does need to move to a new column it does rather than assuming it needs to?

Comment: @LeeB As of now, I don't think so, JS or jQuery will be the way... You just tagged CSS so I answered :)

Comment: Good point. Yeah no worries, i'm surprised in the age of technology that CSS is lagging as far behind as it is!

Comment: @LeeB It is not lagging, browsers are inconsistent in terms of support, where IE is the king, so we need to use proprietary properties, fall back scripts conditional stylesheets etc :) and moreover, I've heard that CSS4 will be coming soon, and yet CSS3 has not yet accepted fully

Comment: IE is the king? IE is possibly the worst one, also, it's just CSS, i read up into it they just update the same CSS documentation rather than building from scratch.

Comment: @LeeB That's why I said, IE is king **inconsistent in terms of support, where IE is the king,** :)

Comment: Oh im with you, top browser but its worst out of them all :)

Comment: @LeeB Yea, I just understand why they don't make it just like other browsers

Comment: Because it is Microsoft and they have a habit of being very awkward haha